# How to fill image in background without stretching?

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout

I want following type of background from my image:

[image]

This is **NOT** a duplicate question because I've tried following solutions:

1) [First one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679366/android-background-image-to-fill-screen)
2) [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400782/android-scale-a-drawable-or-background-image)
3) [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973661/how-to-adjust-background-image-size-to-fit-the-app-screen-size-in-android)

What these answers suggest is use of following attributes of image view:

```
android:scaleType="..."
```

I've tried each available values for this. What I'm getting is:

[image]

Or a very small image in the center, if I use `android:scaleType="center"`.

Following is my layout file for this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.admin.georeminder.MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:src="@mipmap/landscape"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So what am I missing here? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

**EDIT**

I've also tried following combination:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Instead of `match_parent` for width and height, use `wrap_content`

Comment: then it displays very small image at top left corner.

Comment: This is because the picture dimensions (width and height) are smaller than the screen size. You need a picture image file with larger dimensions.

Comment: no! Image size is 4288*2848 pixels. with size of 1.45 MB

Comment: Are you seeing this on layout designer or in device? Also, you should place images inside Res/drawable instead of Res/mipmap, mipmap is only for app launcher icons.

Comment: yes it is same when I run the app. Should I change the location ?

Comment: @Kaushal28 When I keep the image in drawable folder it is working fine. Did you try that?

Comment: Your question says that you're asking how to do FILL but in the picture you provided you are showing a centered image, not fill. Since you marked Alexandre's response as the answer I am assuming you did not want fill but rather center. In Android "centerCrop" is the tag used for fill and "center" is used for center. For a better understanding of terms see the Android documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

Comment: @technoman23 that's why you down voted my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your image file in Res/drawable instead of Res/mipmap.

Res/mipmap is for app launcher icons only

Try this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:src="@drawable/landscape"
    android:scaleType="center" />
```

Comment: Yeah just replaced this image to `drawable` folder, but the result is same.

Comment: @Kaushal28 Updated

Answer (score 1):

use fitxy and use adjustviewbond=true

Answer (score 1):

Set  scaleType with centerCrop and centerInParent in your imageview

```
    <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:src="@mipmap/landscape"       
    />
```

Comment: sry but it is giving the same result as previous. just image is stretched vertical slightly.

Comment: set android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: I told I've tries all this combinations.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342463/stretch-image-to-fit

Answer (score 1):

You could use FrameLayout and ImageView as background

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPlaylistItemBg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/img_dsh" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```