# How to set an image as background for layouts with specific size in android studio?

Tags: android

I have 4activity and I want to set an image for these activities, I set the `android:background="@drawable/background"`property but it scales the image but I want this image set as a title image(set the background image size). I don't want to use ImageView because I want other views locate on the background Image.
how can I do this?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973661/how-to-adjust-background-image-size-to-fit-the-app-screen-size-in-android

Comment: So basically what you're looking for is an image that you can use as a title that is consistent with all your activities, is that what you want?

Comment: yes and also I want to determine height and width for this image